# MIPS array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, mips

I want to write a program that reads and displays an array of strings in MIPS language.

However, my current solution is displaying only the last string that I've entered.

Can anyone help please?

### Here is my program:

```
.data

string: .space 20
array: .space 200
enter: .asciiz "Enter a string:\n"

.text

li $t0,0 
li $t2, 3

loop: 

beqz $t2, display
li $v0,4
la $a0,enter
syscall

la $t1, string
li $v0, 8
move $a0,$t1
li $a1, 20
syscall


sw $a0,array($t0)
addi, $t1,$t1,20
addi $t0,$t0,4
addi $t2,$t2, -1
j loop

display:

li $t2,3
add $t0,$zero,$zero

loop2:
beqz $t2, exit
lw $t3,array($t0)
li $v0,4
move $a0,$t3
syscall
addi $t0,$t0,4
addi $t2,$t2,-1
j loop2

exit:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense to me (the data structures), can you explain why do you think the entered string will be stored in array, and how? Also how do you want to store the final array? Do you want to have Nx20 fixed width strings in memory (i.e. next string starts at +20 offset from previous), or do you want the strings to occupy minimal space, and have array with pointers at beginning of each string, i.e. 20x "a" array will occupy only 40+80=120 bytes (nul terminated "a" = 2B, 20x pointer = 80B), instead of 20x20 = 400 bytes?

Comment: And use the built-in debugger in your simulator to single step your current code and watch what it does and try to find out how did you came with that, and what did confuse you to write this, and try to figure out what you originally did want, and why there's no chance this code would do that.

Comment: I have to realize in MIPS language the equivalent of an array of structures in C  where a structure contains many strings and integers. So I'm trying at first to save strings in an array and this is what I did. What am I supposed to do in such case?

Comment: I am a beginner in MIPS so if someone please could give me an example of how to implement an array of structures in this language for a university project I would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: In C such array can be done by different ways... consider `char strings[10][200];` vs `char* [10];` .. design your data structures first, however you wish. Use either fixed memory structure, or pointers for dynamic-length values like strings. Fixed memory is often simpler to code, but the data will take lot more memory even if strings are short. At this stage (designing memory layout of data structures) this question is not bound to assembler or MIPS, bytes are bytes everywhere.  ... I mean, study first what is byte, what is computer memory, and how for example C stores structures into memory.

Comment: And in your code I don't see any "save string to array", there no copying of string bytes happening at all, so it looks like you don't understand how those things are stored in memory, and how instructions in assembly work with memory, which leads us back to the previous advice, of studying how those things work, and then watching in debugger what you did write and how it doesn't do anything you did want. Then check any tutorial for MIPS assembly to get the basics under skin, like how to copy values from/to memory, then focus on arrays and structures later, when you are stronger in basics.

Comment: and BTW, if you will have fixed-sizes structure, you can point the input system call directly to the destination, to avoid any copying of string, because it will be inputted into the final place already. So then you need only to adjust the input target buffer ahead of each syscall.

Comment: I will improve my knowledge and skills but at the current time i need help immediately about how to implement an array of structures where a structure contains 2 strings and 2 ints in MIPS language. Please and thank you in advance.